# Can one cases's owner id be assigned to another case?

Tags: case

I have a case which has ownerid as'005b0000000suX5AAI' . i want to assign this id to a new case which is going to be created.  Is this possible ? If yes, please tell me how.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible if you have owner of 1st case which is already created.
for example:

```
case case1= [select id,ownerId from case where id='case id whose owner is to be copied'];

case case2=new case();

case2.Status = 'New';

case2.ownerId = case1.ownerId;

insert case2;
```